# Unable to execute targeted delete in Terraform

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-gcp

I have the following resource in my `main.tf` which I'm trying to delete. The resource exists in `terraform.tfstate` file.

```
module "sql_instance_01" {
  source = "../../modules/sql-instance"

  name = "tf-test-mysql-1"
  project = "proj-test"
}
```

The resource I'm trying to use is-

```
resource "google_sql_database_instance" "mysql_instance"
```

However, when I run targeted destroy, it does not work. Tried multiple permutations and combinations-

```
$ terraform plan -destroy -target google_sql_database_instance.sql_instance_01
Refreshing Terraform state in-memory prior to plan...
The refreshed state will be used to calculate this plan, but will not be
persisted to local or remote state storage.


------------------------------------------------------------------------

No changes. Infrastructure is up-to-date.
```

```
$ terraform plan -destroy -target google_sql_database_instance.tf-test-mysql-1
Refreshing Terraform state in-memory prior to plan...
The refreshed state will be used to calculate this plan, but will not be
persisted to local or remote state storage.


------------------------------------------------------------------------

No changes. Infrastructure is up-to-date.
```

```
$ terraform plan -destroy -target sql_instance_01.tf-test-mysql-1
Refreshing Terraform state in-memory prior to plan...
The refreshed state will be used to calculate this plan, but will not be
persisted to local or remote state storage.


------------------------------------------------------------------------

No changes. Infrastructure is up-to-date.
```

```
$ terraform plan -destroy -target mysql_instance.tf-test-mysql-1
Refreshing Terraform state in-memory prior to plan...
The refreshed state will be used to calculate this plan, but will not be
persisted to local or remote state storage.


------------------------------------------------------------------------

No changes. Infrastructure is up-to-date.
```

Am I invoking destroy incorrectly? or am I missing anything here?

Comment: You need to specify the full path to the resource. Use whatever `terraform state list` shows as the path to the required resource.

Comment: Perfect! That did it. Thanks